# There is unexpected duplicate records in my informatica mapping. I am unable to find from where they are coming?

Tags: etl, data-warehouse, informatica, informatica-powercenter

In my informatica mapping, initially the source was relational one. I changed it to file and now duplicate records are coming in the target.For example there is only 750 records in my source but in my target 800 records are getting populated. I checked and noticed few of the records are getting duplicated somehow

By using sorter transformation the issue can be resolved but I want to know how or why this duplicate records are getting created

Comment: Hi - as you have provided no information about what your mapping is doing I’m not sure how you expect anyone to help you? Check the log files (you may need to turn the logging level up) and see in which component the record counts are increasing

Comment: its possible you have a join in the mapping. its also possible SQ may have a distinct in case it was a table.

Comment: We need at least some overview of the process. A screenshot of the mapping would help a lot!

Comment: Thank you everyone for your inputs. The issue is resolved. Actually there was a filter condition when the source type was relational which got removed when it was changed to file.